# Sometimes Meteor.users.findOne(username:'john') returns undefined?

Tags: meteor

I'm not sure why this code works once in a while and fails other times:

```
var u = Meteor.users.findOne(username:'john');
console.log(u);
```

When I go to my page for the first time, sometimes the `console.log(u)` shows some results.  But if I press refresh, `console.log(u)` shows undefined.  I can't consistently reproduce one issue or the other.  It seems pretty random when i get undefined or a collection.  What's wrong with my code?  How do I consistently get a collection for the variable `u`?

Comment: i have this weird behavior too. Whenever i refresh the page, sometime it will give `undefined`

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code, you just can't be certain when this code will execute: before or after the user collection is synced to the client. There are various ways around that, e.g., using the ready() method returned from a subscription, or using waitOn when using iron-router. But in most cases you can just ignore this, because reactivity will take care of it an update your page everywhere it depends on this data.

Comment: like christian says there is nothing wrong with this, you can fix the annoying undefined with a simple if(u){ // console.log(u)} and done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Christian Fritz said in comment on your question, it's probably a matter of collection not being fully loaded when your code is executed. If you use `iron:router`, you can use `subscribe` or `waitOn` as described there: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-waiton-option so the page is loaded only when the collections are ready (meaning they are fully loaded).
You can also put it in a helper or use a [Tracker Autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) to detect when your entry is available and then do whatever you want to do with it.

Edit: A sample for iron:router below

```
// myproject.jsx

var Cars = new Mongo.Collection('cars');
if(Meteor.isServer)
{
    Meteor.publish("myCollections", function () {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    });
    Meteor.publish("anotherCollection", function(){
      return Cars.find();
    });
}

//lib/router.js

Router.route('/my-page', {
    name: 'myPage',
    layoutTemplate: 'myPage',
    waitOn: function() {
        'use strict';
        return [Meteor.subscribe('myCollection'),Meteor.subscribe('anotherCollection')];
    },
    data: function() {
        'use strict';
        return Collection.findOne();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried a few of the sample code for the waitOn, subscribe and publish but get various unexpected result. Can you post an example code specific to my situation?  Then I'll understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Oh wait, I think I finally got it to work...i'll post sample code shortly

Comment: I added some more missing code to make things work specific to my projects